# How do I get my windows controls back?

Tags: 11.04, unity, window-buttons

By accident my window top decoration seem to have dissapeared in Unity. Window buttons or  application menus are not displayed on the top panel. How can I regain control over this window?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Compiz running, you should still be able to drag the window around while holding the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key.

Answer (score 1):

Either you log out and in again or do a `unity --reset` from command line (it'll flicker then screen a couple of times).

Answer (score 1):

If you got CompizConfig Settings Manager, make sure the **Windows Decorations** on. Also try unity --replace.